# How to modify Gatsby Starter Lightbox to query specific image directories?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to utilize the Lightbox component from [Gatsby Starter Lightbox](https://github.com/416serg/gatsby-starter-lightbox) to display a few image galleries on different pages.

As the starter component is setup by default, it only supports one directory of images, as set in [gatsby-config.js](https://github.com/416serg/gatsby-starter-lightbox/blob/02ad0fc20e8aa5e2fb32a995cd1689cd27295c56/gatsby-config.js#L27)

```
   `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `cars`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/cars/`,
      },
```

Then in [pages/index.js](https://github.com/416serg/gatsby-starter-lightbox/blob/02ad0fc20e8aa5e2fb32a995cd1689cd27295c56/src/pages/index.js#L20) it passes the Lightbox component all of the images.

```
<Lightbox images={data.allImageSharp.edges} />
```

```
    allImageSharp {
      edges {
        node {
          sizes(maxWidth: 1800) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to provide it a custom set of images, based on different image directories.

I'm new to Gatsby and React and couldn't figure out how to filter allImageSharp by directory, but I did figure out a way with allFile...though I ran into a type error trying to use it.

What I tried:

```
  gallery: allFile(filter: {relativeDirectory: {eq: "screenshots/producta"}, extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(png)/"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        relativeDirectory
        extension
      }
    }
  }
```

But in trying to utilize that with:

```
<Lightbox images={props.data.gallery} />
```

I got the error "TypeError: images.map is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

So I think I may have figured it out. What I've done appears to be working, but I would caution that I don't know how "right" or good of a solution it is.

I seemed to have been on a working path earlier in my question, but had a few things off.

Here's what I've done:

I updated my query so it would return childImageSharp for each node, so now it's returning the equivalent of what was being returned in with allImageSharp from the starter pack. However, this structure is slightly different, so I also had to update the Lightbox.js component to properly reference these changes. You'll notice that my query has a subfield called 'fluid', instead of 'sizes'. This is because I noticed 'sizes' is deprecated in Gatsby 2.x. Fluid appears to return the same fields though. So I updated 'sizes' to 'fluid' everywhere it was referenced in Lightbox.js.

```
<Lightbox images={props.data.gallery.edges} />
```

```
    gallery: allFile(
      filter: {
        relativeDirectory: { eq: "screenshots/producta" }
        extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(png)/" } 
      }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          relativeDirectory
          extension
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              base64
              tracedSVG
              aspectRatio
              src
              srcSet
              srcWebp
              srcSetWebp
              sizes
              originalImg
              originalName
              presentationWidth
              presentationHeight
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible to resolve several paths with `gatsby-source-filesystem`:

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
      name: `cars`,
      path: `${__dirname}/src/images/cars/`,
    },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
      name: `productScreenshots`,
      path: `${__dirname}/src/screenshots/products/`,
    },
},
```

Notice the `name` property? It could be used to query exactly that subset:

```
query getCarImages {
  allFile(
    filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "cars"}}
  ) {
    nodes {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can dump all your images into `src/images`, point plugin at it once and then filter based on subdirectories' paths as mentioned in your examples.